# Find sufficient and necessary conditions on $x$ and $y$ such that $x>y$ and $⌈x⌉<1+⌊y⌋$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Find sufficient and necessary conditions on $x$ and $y$ such that $x>y$ and  $$⌈x⌉<1+⌊y⌋$$ where $⌈x⌉$ is the ceiling function of $x$ and $⌊y⌋$ is the floor of $y$. I have no idea to start.

Comment: Your inequality is never true.

Comment: @corindo Unless x=y and both are integer. That's the answer, actually.

Comment: But in the condition it says $x > y$.

Comment: @corindo My. Bad. Sorry for silly comment, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x=\lceil x \rceil - a$ and $y=\lfloor y \rfloor + b$ with $a,b \in [0,1)$. Then $$x>y \iff \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor y \rfloor > a+b$$ and $$\lceil x \rceil < 1+\lfloor y \rfloor \iff \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor y \rfloor < 1$$

From the above we get $$1 > \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor y \rfloor > a+b \ge 0$$ which is impossible as $\lceil x \rceil - \lfloor y \rfloor \in \mathbb Z$. Thus there don't exist $x,y$ such that both inequalities hold.